# How to get headline to break at the correct place

Tags: html, css

I am new to css and would like to learn the correct way or best practices way to get a headline to break to a new line. I have attached an image to show what I want the result in a computer web browser to look like.

[image]

Here is the html for the page:

```
<div class="tagline">
            <h1><span>Transform your written</span> work into a <strong>masterpiece<strong></h1>
    </div>
```

Here is the css:

```
h1{
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.2;
}



.tagline {
    background: #abdfe8 url(images/bg-tagline.png) no-repeat;
    height: 450px;
    text-align: center;
}



.tagline h1 {
    padding: 90px 0 60px 0;
    width: 520px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.tagline h1 span {
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}
```

This works well as shown in the image. However, as a new css developer I would like to know the best practices would for coding this or if I'm on the right track.

Comment: so you want the breaks to be done by css instead of adjusting your html by using <br> for example?

Comment: I would like to use `<br>` tag for that... and as for css method you can also set `display: block;` to your `<span>` tag.

Comment: you are on right track :p. that's how I would did it too  :p

Comment: I was not going to use the br tag because I was thinking later I would make the site responsive and having that br would make the line break possibly with only one word on a line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `span` like:

```
<div class="tagline">
  <h1>
    <span>Transform your written</span> 
    <span>work into a <strong>masterpiece<strong></span>
  </h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
span{
   display: block;
}
```

Comment: This works without me having to declare a  width for the h1 block. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
span.dontwrapthistext{ display:inline-block; }
```

in this span the text will not be wrapped

```
<span class="dontwrapthistext">Insert text here that you don't want to be wrapped</span>
```

so your whole text will be wrapped into the desired blocks first, and then to smaller blocks if needed